# spy on argument to class method using sinon

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, tdd, sinon, chai

I have a class that I want to spy on to check for the arguments that the method has been called with.

```
class Animal {
  constructor() {
     this.animals = [];
  }

  add(animal) {
    this.animals.push(animal);
  }
}
```

My test file looks like this

```
const chai = require('chai');
const sinon  = require('sinon');
const Lazy = require('../lazy');

it('should be able to add an animal', function () {
    const animal = new Animal();
    const add = sinon.spy(animal, 'add');
    animal.add('cat')
    expect(animal).to.have.been.called.with('cat');
});
```

the spy isn't working. I am wondering how to check what is being called using sinon.

Comment: Spy on the prototype?

Comment: `sinon.spy(Animal.prototype, 'add')`?

Answer (score 0):

`animal` is the object, the spy is actually `add`, so it should be:

```
expect(add).to.have.been.called.with('cat');
```

Answer (score 0):

Patrick is right about the code, you need to validate the `spy` not the object, but your code did still not run without alterations. I made a [functioning example on RunKit](https://runkit.com/fatso83/chai-spy-example). It seems you need to use `calledWith` as well, but you might have used some other setup (which was missing). Check out the code :-)

So change the expectation to

```
expect(add).to.have.been.calledWith('cat');
```